# Next Bigger Number with the same digits Solution

Tags: c#

Please review my code. I would love to know what improvements I can make in terms of efficiency as well as readability. Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public class Bojo
{
      public static long NextBiggerNumber(long n)
        {
            //check if bigger number is even a possibility
            if (NoBiggerNumber(n))
                return -1;
            var results = FindPivot(n.ToString());
            //Console.WriteLine(results.FirstPart + "," + results.PivotIndex + "," + results.SecondPart);
            string newSecondPart = ReorganizeSecondPart(results.SecondPart);
            return Convert.ToInt64(results.FirstPart + newSecondPart);
        }

        private static string ReorganizeSecondPart(string secondPart)
        {
            string newSecondPart = "";
            var secondPartNumbers = secondPart.Select(c => c - '0').ToList();
            //Step 1 - Find second largest digit for pivot index i.e. 0
            var sortedAsc = secondPartNumbers.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();
            var duplicatesRemoved = sortedAsc.Distinct().ToList();
            var nextPivotIndex = duplicatesRemoved.IndexOf(secondPartNumbers[0]) + 1;
            newSecondPart += duplicatesRemoved[nextPivotIndex].ToString();
            //Step 2 - Rearrange the rest of the second part excluding the new pivot
            sortedAsc.Remove(duplicatesRemoved[nextPivotIndex]);
            newSecondPart += String.Concat(sortedAsc.Select(n => n.ToString()));
            return newSecondPart;
        }

        private static (string FirstPart, int PivotIndex, string SecondPart) FindPivot(string strNumber)
        {
            var numbers = strNumber.Select(c => c - '0').ToArray();
            for (int i = numbers.Count() - 1; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                if (numbers[i] > numbers[i - 1])
                {
                    int pivot = i - 1;
                    string left = strNumber.Substring(0, i - 1);
                    string right = strNumber.Substring(i - 1);
                    return (left, pivot, right);
                }
            }
            return ("",-1, "");
        }
        public static bool NoBiggerNumber(long n)
        {
            string strN = n.ToString();
            if (strN.Length == 1)
                return true;
            if (strN.Distinct().Count() == 1)
                return true;
            for (int i = 1; i < strN.Length; i++)
            {
                if (strN[i] > strN[i - 1])
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello Emma, could you explain in more detail what your code is supposed to do? Otherwise we can't really review it,,,